# flutter run with flutter create app throws error

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

when I run the flutter create default app . my app is running but getting an error and it quits.
The error is :
Error connecting to the service protocol: HttpException: Connection closed before full header was received while flutter run http://127.0.0.1:64730/WQfPVkoQWyk=/
How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the emulator then changing the Android version from Q to Pie should solve the issue. This issue is addressed [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/32696#issuecomment-492687564)

Comment: I was using Nexus

Comment: What is the Android version?